# One CSS Syntax help

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
#ie .page               /*all page class under #ie*/
#ie > .page             /* .page only in #ie's direct child*/
#ie.page                /* What does this mean?*/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The third one affects elements with an `ie` id which also have `page` as a class.